# php multiple string replace without recursion

Tags: php

So I have this piece of code

```
$text2 = "abcd";
$text2 = str_replace(
    array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
    array('dbac ', 'cabd ', 'bacd ', 'adbc '),
    $text2
);
```

and text2 is "adbc bacadbc abadbc abacadbc bacadbc abadbc bacadbc adbc" but I wanted to have dbac cabd bacd adbc. How to avoid that recursion replacing?

Comment: if you use only one-symbol parterns, function `strtr` will help - https://eval.in/884555

Comment: OK I changed code to show that it's not simple one symbol or reverse

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could simply use the PHP [strrev](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function:

```
$text2 = "aabbccdd";
$text2 = strrev($text2); // ddccbbaa
```

Comment: That ddccbbaa is just an example. I have to do different replacement